# CSS Caption issue

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with a caption.
How can I let the caption appear under each photo, when I hover over it.

The problem is that they all appear on one side at the bottom left corner.

Here is the HTML code:

```
<div id="content2">
<ul style="width: 5020px; height: 600px;">  
<li class="image" style="width: 392px;"><img src="images/pr1x.jpg" ><p class="caption">1st    caption</p></li>
<li class="image" style="width: 392px;"><img src="images/pr2x.jpg" ><p class="caption">2st    caption</p></li>
</ul></div>
```

Here is the CSS code:

```
li.image p.caption {
position:absolute;
display: none;
font-size: 28px;
color: red;
}
li.image:hover p.caption {
display: list-item;
}​
#content2{
width: 150%;
height: 600px;
float:left;
overflow:hidden;
}
#content2 p{
width: 150%;
}
.scrollbar-hor{
background-color: #e5e2de;
height: 24px;
width: 150%;
float:left;             
}
.handle-hor{
height: 25px;
width: 400px;
background: url(http://brafitting.info/images/bar.jpg) no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd try the new HTML5 elements `figure` and `figcaption`
http://html5doctor.com/the-figure-figcaption-elements/

### HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <figure>
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/200">
            <figcaption>Caption</figcaption>
        </figure>
    </li> 
    <li>
        <figure>
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/200">
            <figcaption>Caption</figcaption>
        </figure>
    </li>
</ul>
```

### CSS

```
figcaption  {  display: none;}
figure:hover figcaption {display: block;}
li {display:inline-block;border: 1px solid green;}
figure {border: 1px solid gold; margin:0;}
ul { margin: 0; padding:0; 1px solid blue;}
li { margin:0; padding:0;vertical-align: top;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5Pcxv/10/

Comment: thank You for replay
the problem here that it's not working with <li>
and i want to display them horizontally with scroll 
look here [link](http://jsfiddle.net/5Pcxv/2/)
origenal [link](http://brafitting.info/?page_id=132)

Comment: You need `inline-block` for li display, because figure has display: block http://jsfiddle.net/5Pcxv/10/